# How To Use Distinct Function For Two Column And Sum on PHP MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have table like this :

```
EmployeeID       date1        date2      time1    time2     totaltime
12345            2015-09-15   2015-09-15 10:00:00 15:00:00  5
12345            2015-09-15   2015-09-15 08:00:00 09:00:00  1
12345            2015-09-17   2015-09-17 08:00:00 09:00:00  1
12345            2015-09-19   2015-09-19 10:00:00 15:00:00  5
78901            2015-09-30   2015-09-30 10:00:00 15:00:00  5
```

The problem is i want to `distinct` the `EmployeeID` and the `date1` coloumn and sum the total time onl for one `employeeID` who has same date (based on `date1`). You can see on my example result below :

```
EmployeeID       date1        date2      time1    time2     totaltime
12345            2015-09-15   2015-09-15 10:00:00 15:00:00  5
12345            2015-09-15   2015-09-15 08:00:00 09:00:00  1
```

so, the result is 6 (5+1).

I have tried to use this syntax :

```
SELECT DISTINCT (EmployeeID, date1) as totaldate
```

but nothing happened.

Where is the problem?

And I'm sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT EmployeeID, date1, SUM(totaltime) as totaldate
FROM your_table
GROUP BY EmployeeID, date1
```

Comment: i have tried this but i got this message #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'EmployeeID,date1, SUM(totaltime) as totaldate FROM timetable GROUP ' at line 1

Comment: SELECT * EmployeeID, date1, SUM(totaltime) as totaldate
FROM timetable
GROUP BY EmployeeID, date1